# Unity edge of screen duplication error in android

Tags: unity-game-engine

In unity 2019.2.9f1, I got a strange error in some android devices such as LG G6.

I think the error is related to my script using to adjust viewport rect to screen size.

The script is as follows:

```
public static void AdjustCamera()
{
    if (Constants.ASPECT_RATIO < Camera.main.aspect)
    {
        float newCameraWidth = Constants.ASPECT_RATIO / Camera.main.aspect;
        float newCameraX = (1 - newCameraWidth) / 2f;
        Camera.main.rect = new Rect(newCameraX, 0f, newCameraWidth, 1f);
    }
}
```

And the error is like below:

[image: unity end of screen bug]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved this problem adding another camera with Clear Flags = Solid Color, Culling Mask = Nothing and Depth = 2.